# SQL Average ignoring NULL values with INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to average multiple columns but am receiving NULL values. I want to replace the NULL with a value of 0. I also need to INNER JOIN a few tables to get all the information I need.

here is what I have so far:

```
select 
    m.mstr_list_item_desc,
    p.last_name,
    p.first_name,
    AVG((l.percentage_1 + l.percentage_2 + l.percentage_3 + l.percentage_4 +          l.percentage_5 + l.percentage_6 +l.percentage_7 + l.percentage_8 + l.percentage_9 + l.percentage_10 + l.percentage_11 + l.percentage_12 + l.percentage_13)/13) as Total_average
from LMA_ob_compliance_ as l
INNER JOIN patient_encounter as pe
    on l.enc_id=pe.enc_id
INNER JOIN provider_mstr as p
    on p.provider_id=pe.rendering_provider_id
INNER JOIN mstr_lists as m
    on m.mstr_list_item_id=p.provider_subgrouping1_id
group by m.mstr_list_item_desc, p.last_name, p.first_name
order by p.last_name asc
```

A majority of those percentage columns are NULL, but i want to be able to include that NULL as a 0 in my calculate.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you had trouble implementing Jakub's answer (which I upvoted, as it is correct), here's your full query with the application of `ISNULL` all 13 times.  I also took the liberty of fixing some formatting for the sake of readability and changing some hardcoded values to end in `.0` to make certain you never get bit by implicit conversion.

```
select 
    m.mstr_list_item_desc,
    p.last_name,
    p.first_name,
    AVG(
        (
        ISNULL(l.percentage_1, 0.0) + 
        ISNULL(l.percentage_2, 0.0) + 
        ISNULL(l.percentage_3, 0.0) + 
        ISNULL(l.percentage_4, 0.0) + 
        ISNULL(l.percentage_5, 0.0) + 
        ISNULL(l.percentage_6, 0.0) +
        ISNULL(l.percentage_7, 0.0) + 
        ISNULL(l.percentage_8, 0.0) + 
        ISNULL(l.percentage_9, 0.0) + 
        ISNULL(l.percentage_10, 0.0) + 
        ISNULL(l.percentage_11, 0.0) + 
        ISNULL(l.percentage_12, 0.0) + 
        ISNULL(l.percentage_13, 0.0)
        )
        /13.0) as Total_average
from 
    LMA_ob_compliance_ as l
    INNER JOIN patient_encounter as pe on l.enc_id=pe.enc_id
    INNER JOIN provider_mstr as p on p.provider_id=pe.rendering_provider_id
    INNER JOIN mstr_lists as m on m.mstr_list_item_id=p.provider_subgrouping1_id
group by 
    m.mstr_list_item_desc, 
    p.last_name, 
    p.first_name
order by 
    p.last_name asc
```

Comment: Thank you both, that gave me what I needed. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

Use [`ISNULL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) to replace a `NULL` with a value you want

```
ISNULL(l.percentage_1, 0) + isnull(l.percentage_2, 0) + ...
```

Comment: Thank you Jakub! I am not getting a syntax error near the keywork 'from'

Comment: @Lindsay you probably implemented this answer incorrectly and/or with a typo.  I made another answer that passes syntax checking for your entire query, with a little bit of additional cleanup.  See if that helps.